# Can't change shipping method in WooCommerce on Cart & Checkout page

Tags: woocommerce

I'm having a real struggle with fixing the following issue.
In attached screenshot you can see I have 2 different shipping methods setup.
However, whenever I want to choose the Local Pickup (Free) as the method I get the little spinner from Wordpress for a couple of seconds but the selection changes back to Flat Rate. I have the same issue on the cart as the checkout page.

[image]

Things I already tried: disabling all plugins, change the active theme, update wordpress, nothing helped so far :/
Don't see any js issues also.

Has anyone got an idea perhaps? :)
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 

The only things in red at the status page are:
Server Environment: ✕ Default timezone is Europe/Brussels - it should be UTC (seems irrelevant)
Database: woocommerce_sessions   Table does not exist

Also didn't spot any errors in the console.

Comment: Managed to fix the issue by creating that "woocommerce_sessions" table i n the database. Checked the database definition in another woocommerce I developed which did have that database table. Still don't understand why the store wouldn't have that (seemingly important) table ... Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: **Very nice shot, congratulations** … I completely forgot this kind of issue. This seems to happen when the database user set in wp-config.php has not enough rights or when updating an old install…